# Accessing a deleted, then re-created global variable

Tags: python-3.x

If we delete the global variable in function and recreate same variable in function so we cannot access it outside the function but it still accessible after deleting how?

**CODE:**

```
f=100
print(f)

def change():
    global f
    print(f)
    f=200
    print(f)
    del f #deleted
    #print(f) we get error for this line
    f=500# again created as local variable
    g=5000# this is also local means can't access outside the function
    print(f)

change()
print(f)#We delete f but how it exist.although it is local var of change function
print(g)#Here we get error that  g is not defined
```

Comment: Format your code properly so that we can see the indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f` is declared global; when you recreate it, it is recreated in the global scope.
`g` on the other hand is local, and cannot be accessed outside its scope.

```
def change():
    global f      # f is global 
    del f         # deleted
    f = 500       # recreated as GLOBAL variable
    g = 5000      # this is LOCAL ==>> can't access outside the scope

change()
print(f)  # f was deleted, then recreated in the global scope
print(g)  # raises NameError: name 'g' is not defined
```